# USB devices undetected and/or non-functional

Tags: windows-10, usb, drivers

I have a Windows 10 PC with 4 front-side USB 3.0 ports, and 4 back-side USB 3.0 ports.
Since I have a lot of USB devices (mainly external HDDs), I decided to use a 10-port USB hub (always 3.0) in order to have more USB ports at my disposal, not all of the peripherals use USB 3.0, some might use a lower standard (e.g. a 3D printer I have is using a 2.0 USB port).

Many of these peripherals remain undetected, but they are working by detaching another peripheral and attaching the non-working one to one of these front-side or back-side ports.

My guess is that there is a limit on the USB peripherals that a system can manage.

I tried updating the drivers, however it seems that all of these are with the correct version. I also tried uninstalling an reinstalling them, to no avail.
The USB hub is working fine, but only detects (at the moment) 2 peripherals of the 5 i have attached.

Any hints on what might be the issue?

Thanks in advance for any input you might have.

Comment: Is it a powered or unpowered USB Hub? It is always better to use a powered hub when connected multiple devices ...

Comment: It is a powered USB hub. I also forgot to mention that I tried replacing it also with different models, but the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

By looking at the devmgmt.msc tool and the relative logs, the returned errors were "Error Code 10" "Insufficient system resources to call API" (Maybe roughly translated).

It appears that Windows 10 (and probably other previous versions as well) have a power saving option which also persists the "High performance" option, which is relative to USB power saving.

I disabled this feature, and it seems that all of my peripherals and devices, which are connected to the system, are now working properly.